# How do I debug in Xcode and cocos2d

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

Im new to xCode and cocos2d. And i dont understand how the debugger works. When there is an error: int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate"); Thread 1: Prgram received signal: EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
But how do i see what line in what object causing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following code will give you a warning at compile time

```
    NSString * dud = [NSString stringWithFormat:"a bad string specifier without the @"];
```

yet if your execution path passes through there, you will get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS blues at run time. Recommend you step through these warnings carefully. Sometimes the issues navigator and debug panels will be far from useful (disassembled code, no stack trace).

Answer (score 0):

Use Tabs in left top corner. In "Issues" tab you must click at issue.

Comment: I only got warnings there. Yellow triangles.

Comment: Yes. Yellow triangle. Errors must be there too if you have errors.